# D3 v5 working with Year only in timeParse

Tags: d3.js

I am currently loading in csv to d3 using the .dsv method.
The csv containts two columns: year and avg_price.
The year column is only 1901, 1902, 1903 and contains no month or day.

```
year, avg_price
1901, 25.20
1902, 28.30
1903, 19.25
1904, 21.50
```

d3.dsv import will return a string, but I want to convert this information to a datetime object as just 'year' so that I can graph the results to a barchart.

I've already tried running the below upon import but it doesn't seem to work.

`var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y")`

Are there any good resources for v5 that explain how to parse a partial date into a date object for charts?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new Date(d.year, 0, 1)` in the function to convert your first column to a javascript `Date` object (first January of each year).

(Beware of the spaces in the tsv string).

Example:

```js
const csv = `year,avg_price
1901,25.20
1902,28.30
1903,19.25
1904,21.50`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, d => ({
  year: new Date(+d.year, 0, 1),
  avg_price: +d.avg_price,
}));

const format = d3.timeFormat('%Y');

const ul = d3.select("#app").append('ul');


ul.selectAll('li')
  .data(data)
  .join('li')
  .text(d => `${format(d.year)}: ${d.avg_price}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: this still creates a month and day for the date... is it not possible to just have a date object with just year? Essentially, I want to plot year on its own but I'm having trouble doing so.

Comment: No, a date needs a month and a day. But you can plot only the years using `d3.scaleLinear` instead of `d3.scaleTime`, or you can format your date in your plot using [d3.timeFormat('%Y')](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#timeFormat)

Comment: You're welcome. I have edited the answer to use `d3.timeFormat('%Y')`.